# KMP法が分からないので調べているのですが

Tags: アルゴリズム

**[リンク先](http://www.neitef.com/algo0011.html)下表について**

---

**Q1**
・「abbabbababに対するシフト幅」とはどういう意味ですか？
・「検索テキスト」と「パターン」を比較しているわけではなく、事前の「パターン」同士の比較テーブルを作成する時の話？
・「abbabbabab」はパターンのこと？？

---

**Q2**
・備考欄に「一致なし」と記載されていますが、どういう意味？
・「何」と「何」が一致していないのでしょうか？

Comment: リンク先のページの説明はあまりにもざっくりしすぎて、このページだけ読んでもよくわからないかと思います。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%8C%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E2%80%93%E3%83%A2%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E2%80%93%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E6%B3%95

などを読んでみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「abbabbabab」は検索する元文字列の内容
不一致と判断した場合に読み込んでいる文字列とシフト幅

一致していない場合の振る舞いを示しているので、とある検索文字列と、「abbabbabab」が一致していない、ということですね

そもそも一致した場合、ってのは議論の必要はないですから

Comment: なるほど、下表の意味がようやく分かりました。説明分かりやすかったです